# How to exit from the Jenkins pipeline if we have "BUILD FAILED" message

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, pipeline

In one of pipline’s stages, In the log I have a message with build failed , and then a little later i have a successful build message. I want the pipeline to stop when it see a failed build message and not continue, because if it continue, it will see it successful and it will not stop and we will not know that there is a problem in the log

[Build Failed message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vchbQ.png)

[Build Success Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk2MY.png)

Comment: you can raise an error to stop the pipeline once you get the failure message. Use `error`: `error('Build failed')`. You can also use `sh 'exit 1'` to stop the pipeline.

Comment: how i can use this function or option error: error('Build failed') in my pipeline  
stage("Deploy"){
 
      steps {
        script {
         error: error('Build failed')
        }
      }
    
    } Like this?

Comment: No, `stage("Deploy"){ steps { script { error('Build failed') } } }`

Comment: No, I don't want to always see the result Build failed or stop pipeline, i want just stop it whene i have Build failed message in the Log console

Answer (score 0):

Revisiting Jenkins Docs:-

I found that two params needed to be true in order to get status of triggered job to affect the pipeline

```
propagate : boolean (optional)
If enabled (default state), then the result of this step is that of the downstream build (e.g., success, unstable, failure, not built, or aborted). If disabled, then this step succeeds even if the downstream build is unstable, failed, etc.; use the result property of the return value as needed.


wait : boolean (optional)
If true, the pipeline will wait for the result of the build step before jumping to the next step. Defaults to true.
```

My final Code i.e.(SCM Checkout JOB):-

```
build job: 'FrontEnd_Checkout', wait: true, propagate: true, parameters: [string(name: 'BRANCH_NAME', value: "${env.frontend_branch}")]
```